# Search in String Array an order

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

I want to know how search result in String Array with an order :

Exemple :

```
String[] chestOrder = new String[]{"silver", "silver", "silver", "gold", "silver", "silver", "gold", "silver", "silver",
```

If i search :
Silver Silver Silver Gold, how can i get the next String ? So here, it's silver.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is if you have silver continuously 3 times and gold after that, you want to get the next string.

So here in this code it checks whether there are silver silver silver gold in a row and gets the next string to a variable and print it.

```
    String[] chestOrder = new String[]{"silver", "silver", "silver", "gold", "silver", "silver", "gold", "silver", "silver"};
    String next = null;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < chestOrder.length ; i++){
        if(i <= (chestOrder.length - 3)){
            if(chestOrder[i].equals("silver") && chestOrder[i+1].equals("silver") && chestOrder[i+2].equals("silver") && chestOrder[i+3].equals("gold")){
            next = chestOrder[i+4];
            }
        }

    }

    System.out.println(next);
```

Comment: What are the other cases related to this, so I'll try to improve the answer according to those if i can.

Comment: if he wants the result of silver gold, or gold silver or just silver etc ..

Comment: Do you mean a different order?

Comment: no, what about if he wants to search for a different number of search terms. You have and clauses meaning he has to have 4 search terms.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void searchStringArray() {
        String[] chestOrder = { "silver", "silver", "silver", "gold", "silver",
                "silver", "gold", "silver", "silver" };

        String searchString = "silver silver silver gold";
        StringBuilder tempStr = new StringBuilder();
        for (String s : chestOrder) {
            tempStr.append(s + " ");
        }
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(tempStr.toString());
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            if (null != scanner.findInLine(searchString)) {
                System.out.println("" + scanner.next());
            } else {
                scanner.next();
            }
        }
        scanner.close();

    }
```

Comment: Thanks :) But how can i do for have only One result. Because `scanner.next()` return me the rest of my values. Exemple `result = silver silver gold`. But i want to have `result = silver`. Only the first result. It's possible ? If yes, do you know how ? I've try to use `scanner.nextLine` but it's the same

Comment: Did you try this code? I have tested it then posted. plz try once it fulfil's your desired output.